# How do I get Rocky bees in Agrarian Skies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am trying to get rocky bees in order to get the noble princesses so I can make royal jelly. Does anyone know where I can get the bees?

Any tips and tricks would be wonderful. Thanks in advance. The quest I am working on is two actually. One is genetic manipulation and the other is alveary I have completed a lot of other quest logs in the game but just seem to be stuck on getting the right bees together to get royal jelly.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Feed The Beast wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Rocky_Bee) (emphasis mine):

> The Rocky Bee is a type of Bee in the Rocky Branch added by Extra
>   Bees. **They are found in Rocky hives**, which are usually **buried in stone
>   underground**. Rocky bees are the most numerous mundane bees, but **you
>   need to strip-mine to uncover their hives**.

Comment: Strip-mining in Agrarian Skies is kinda difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Rocky Princesses are not needed. Earlier I was trying to get a common princess with a meadows princess and a common drone. I ended up getting common-cultivated,common-meadows, and common-noble.

Also for honey get some purebred cultivated queens. If you can only get one queen wait till there are more than one drone. Then grab one drone and breed it with a princess. Any princess will due but you will want lifespan upgrades to easliy kill the breeds to quickly check your breeds until you get a purebred cultivated princess and drone and you can repeat the process for any princess if desired.

If you need seed oil I recommend creating a 5 by 5 grass area with dispensers with bonemeal and water to destroy the grass for seeds with hoppers at the bottom for collecting seeds and push a button to activate dispensers then press a different button to activate the water.

Also I don't really know how to get them. My best guess would be to go to a low coordinate and place cobblestone around a scented hive in a meadows or forest biome though you should check by booting up a new world in agrarian skies in creative using cheat mode in NEI.

Also did you even check the recipe in NEI?

Noble=Cultivated+Common

Cultivated=Common+Meadows

Common=any bee at bottom[meadows,forest,ETC.]+any bee at bottom

Comment: This doesn't say how to get Rocky Bees, this tells how not to get them.

Comment: Yes but it shows that you don't need them for nobles.

Comment: I think your answer is addressing a different question than the one being asked.

Comment: It isn't asking a question at all.

Comment: I ment addressing a different question.